# phpmyadmin compatibility export and import - unusual characters

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

so, im trying to move database from old server to new server, backup using simple export from phpmyadmin, cant import directly into phpmyadmin due to the size, easier for me to zip the downloaded file, transfer, unzip, and restore using cli,

checking the large backup file created by phpmyadmin, i can see the collation is set to utf8mb4 (see line below in bold), when creating the database on the new server its created as utf8mb4_unicode_ci to match and imported into new server using cli, but whatever reason, after importing, we get strange characters and some things dont load like widgets become corrupt and don't show on the homepage, tried multiple times exporting and importing but maybe theres a better way of doing this to improve compatibility ?

old server

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.3.34-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: cpses_unxyflj15h@localhost
Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)

**/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;**
```

new server

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.11.3-MariaDB-1:10.11.3+maria~ubu2204 - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

importing using -f because it would throw errors about duplicate values

multiple times exporting via phpmyadmin (my only way to export) tried wordpress plugins but just takes a long time, trying to figure out how to get it to work on the new server

Comment: What settings did you use when exporting with PMA? Add a specific example of a row which has imported with incorrect encoding, and include the full output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` for the relevant table from both old and new servers. If you have stored non-latin1 characters in a latin1 field over a latin1 connection, retrieving them over a utf8mb4 connection will output junk.

Comment: Use migrate db plugin export function, on the go you can change the URL & directory location accordingly. URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/